# Should a deep-learning based image classifier include a negative class

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I am building a image classifier similar to alexnet(https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks).

I have 6 categories [people,car,bikes,animals,hydroplanes,boats]. So right now if I give an object that doesn't not belong to the above mentioned classes it gets classified to either of the classes with some probability.

To increase the accuracy is it wise to add more classes or add a negative class?

And if I had to add a negative class what kind of data would I train it on?

Thank You

Comment: As an alternative to having a negative class, you could define a probability threshold. E.g. if the predicted probability is <50% for the maximum likelihood class, just call this "unknown".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what you really want to produce at the end.

You need an algorithm that tells you wether the image you passed is a car, bike, animal, person, hydroplane, boat.

Do the user is supposed to pass an image that represents something else ? If so, you can add a "other" class.

Comment: This is for a surveillance camera system. I pick up agents using other methods and pass them to the Image classifier. So I get a lot of false agents that are just background noise. But they also get classified as one of the classes and sometimes with high probability.

Comment: Then indeed you need to teach your model how to handle frame that doesn't have any of the classes you want it to guess. I suggest you to train your model with a "other" class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what kind of classifier you want to build and available training data.

If you have enough training data for a new class, e.g., train, you can easily add a new class. It is quite straightforward. But the problem remains, if some new object appears at input then what to do....

I think your question is, how to handle a situation when an object(which is not the training set) is presented to the network. In such cases adding a negative class is quite complex as network need enough and clear training data for negative class as well. So one way to deal with this situation is to put a check on the output probabilities. If no training class get say 70% of output probability than classify the input as ambiguous or negative class.